# Tokio: "error: lifetime may not live long enough" when passing closure through channel

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm attempting to pass an async closure between threads in a `tokio` based application, however I am running into a lifetime error I don't understand when trying to make this work.

I've created a minimal example of the issue in [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b11f633a587edc03b1f6516a315fb4fa):

```
use tokio; // 1.32.0

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    
    let (send, recv) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
    
    let val: u32 = 0;
    
    let func = move |foo: &u32| async move { val + foo };

    let _ = send.send(func);
    
    let fut = async move {
    
        let f = recv.await.expect("receiver should not fail");

        let foo: u32 = 1;
        let res = f(&foo).await;
        println!("Result: {}", res);
        assert_eq!(res, 1);
    };

    tokio::spawn(fut).await.expect("thread should succeed");

    
}
```

Which yields this error when compiling:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:33
   |
10 |     let func = move |foo: &u32| async move { val + foo };
   |                           -   - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                           |   |
   |                           |   return type of closure `[async block@src/main.rs:10:33: 10:57]` contains a lifetime `'2`
   |                           let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

If I understand correctly, the error is telling me that the lifetime of the argument to the closure (`foo`) must outlive the return value of the closure.  Why is this the case, why is it not satisfied, and how can I modify the code to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a quirk of closure inference. Unfortunately, there is no good way to prevent it.

If boxing is acceptable, you can box the returned future:

```rust
fn generate_func(val: u32) -> impl Fn(&u32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = u32> + '_ + Send>> {
    move |foo: &u32| Box::pin(async move { val + foo })
}

let func = generate_func(val);
```

The extra function is to force the types on the compiler, because, again, closure inference is quirky.